# Problem involving Kruskal-Katona

Tags: combinatorics

$[n] = \{1,2,...,n\}$, $\mathbb{P}$ denotes powerset, $[n]^{(r)} = \{A \subset [n]: \vert A \vert = r\}$, $\partial \mathcal{A} = \{A-\{x\}: A \in \mathcal{A}, x \in [n]\}$, colex means colexicographic ordering.

Let $\mathcal{A}\subset \mathbb{P}[n]$ be such that $\vert A \vert \geq r$ for all $A \in \mathcal{A}$. Let $B = \{Y \in [n]^{(r)} : Y \subset A\ \text{for some $A \in \mathcal{A}$}\}$. Show that if
$$\vert \mathcal{A} \vert > \sum_{j=r}^m \binom{m}{r} - \binom{m-r}{j-r}$$
then $\vert B \vert \geq \binom{m}{r}$.

Here is what I have so far. We can write $A = \mathcal{A}_r \cup \mathcal{A}_{r+1} \cup \dots \cup \mathcal{A}_n$ where $\mathcal{A}_k$ is the intersection of $\mathcal{A}$ with the set $[n]^{(k)}$ of all $k$-sets. Then, $B = \mathcal{A}_r \cup \partial \mathcal{A}_{r+1} \cup \dots \cup \partial^{n-r}\mathcal{A}_n$. So, $\vert B \vert$ is minimized if all the sets in the union are equal (or nested).

I now want to do something with Kruskal-Katona but I can't quite see how to use the condition on the size of $\mathcal{A}$ to do it. I see that if we consider each $\mathcal{A}_j$ to be the initial segment of colex of size $\binom{m}{j} - \binom{m-r}{j-r}$, then I believe we have that $\partial^{j-r} \mathcal{A}_{j} \subset \mathcal{A}_r$ (by doing this for $j=0,1$ and hoping the formula extends). By KK, this set $\mathcal{A}$ minimizes $B$, so in particular $B$ contains $[m]^{(r)}$ so it must have size $\geq \binom{m}{r}$. But the condition on $\mathcal{A}$ is a strict inequality, which I am not using here. So I think I must have some mistake.

The version of KK that I have seen is that if $\mathcal{A} \subset [n]^{(r)}$ and $C$ is the initial segment of colex of size $\vert C \vert = \vert \mathcal{A} \vert$, then $\vert \partial C \vert \leq \vert \partial \mathcal{A} \vert$.

Comment: You should really consider the possibility that for most reader your notations are not standard and add explanation about what you meant with them.

Comment: Ive added clarifying definitions.